# In Lilypond: Can one absorb the sharps and flats in the key, in order to ease typing?

Tags: lilypond

As I understood from [the tutorial](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/accidentals-and-key-signatures), the short code

> `\key d \major 
>    cis4 d e fis`

would generate

[image].

Is this the only way to type it, or is there a natural way to get the same output by absorbing the 
sharps in the key, i.e. since D major already signals that `c` and `f` really mean `c-sharp` and `f-sharp`, respectively, I'd like to know if it's possible to get the same pdf and midi by typing

> `\key d \major 
>    c4 d e f`

instead?

P.S. Sorry if this is somewhere else in the tutorial, I'm just trying to produce my *hello world* in Lilypond.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is "Yes you can, but doing this is a really bad idea".

It's a bad idea because you will probably soon want to write C natural or F natural with a D major key signature, and if you make "c" mean "c sharp" you won't have a good way to do that. If the key signature changes during the piece, things will quickly get very confusing.

Check out "note names for other languages" in the documentation. For example in English you can use "s" and "f" for sharp and flat, not the Dutch (or Scandinavian) "is" and "es".

If still you want to ignore the above advice and find out how to do it, check the documentation on how Lilypond handles bagpipe music (which is effectively written in the key of D but without a key signature and without accidentals) and look at "bagpipe.ly" to see how the note names are redefined.

Comment: That  makes sense. I just wanted to be sure whether it was the optimal way. What I, as newbie, expected is: if you are already in, say D-Major, then you will likely write more  **cis** than *c* and more *fis* than *f*, and that therefore anytime you are to play/obtain natural-c that there would be a way to write, **cn** or the like, meaning *C-Becuadro*, *c-becarré, c-Auflösungszeichen*. I guess just practice will tell me that the configuration chosen by LiilyPond developers is optimal.

Comment: The basic idea is that defining **what** note is to be written is independent of **how** it is written. Some notation doesn't use key signatures (e.g. orchestral horn parts and guitar tablature, as well as bagpipes). You can define non-standard key signatures. You can define a sequence of notes once, not associated with any particular staff or key signature, and use it on several staves with different notation conventions. There is a `\transpose` command. Making all those options work sensibly when the pitch notation depended on the key signature would be a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You want your Lilypond source file to use the simplest names for the pitches which accord with your key signature. Fine, but if you're going to do that, then, to be consistent with doing that, you should also name the pitches by letters in a way which accords with your key signature. So if you are going to compose in a major key this way, then, in your Lilypond file, type c for your tonic, d for your supertonic, e for your mediant and so on. In other words, type in C major. Then use \transpose to get the correct notation in the sheet music:

```
\version "2.18"
\language "english"

tune = {
    \key d \major
    \transpose c d'' { b, c d e }
}

\score
{
    \new Staff \tune
    \layout { }
}
```